# How to disable textbox on click of button in Vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

```html
<button  @click="verifyOtp"  id="verifybtn"> VERIFY </button>


 <input
                      
                      type="text"
                      id="mobile"
                      v-model="mobile"
                      v-model.trim="$v.mobile.$model"
                      :class="{ 'is-invalid': validationStatus($v.mobile) }"
                      placeholder="Enter your mobile number"
                      v-validate="'required'"
                      :maxlength="maxmobile"
                      
                    />
```

On click of verify button, How to disable the input field in vuejs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To input you add field :disabled, which is initally set to 0 or false and then in method verifyOtp you set it to true or 1.

```
<input
  type="text"
  id="mobile"
  v-model="mobile"
  v-model.trim="$v.mobile.$model"
  :class="{ 'is-invalid': validationStatus($v.mobile) }"
  placeholder="Enter your mobile number"
  v-validate="'required'"
  :maxlength="maxmobile"
  :disabled="disabled == 1" // this field
/>
```

And then in verifyOtp method you set disabled to true:

```
this.disabled = true;
```

Whole example:

```
    <html>
  <head>
    <title>VueJs Introduction</title>
    <script type = "text/javascript" src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.3/vue.min.js">
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id = "intro" style = "text-align:center;">
       <h1>{{ message }}</h1>
       <button @click="test">Switch</button>
    <input type="text" :disabled="disabled == 1" />
    </div>
    <script type = "text/javascript">
      var vue_det = new Vue({
        el: '#intro',
        data: {
          message: 'My first VueJS Task',
          disabled: 0
        },
        methods: {
          test: function() {
            this.disabled = true;
          }
        }
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

With a property, like this:

```
<button  @click="inputDisable = !inputDisable"  id="verifybtn"> VERIFY </button>

 <input
  :disabled="inputDisable"
   type="text"
   id="mobile"
   v-model="mobile"
   v-model.trim="$v.mobile.$model"
   :class="{ 'is-invalid': validationStatus($v.mobile) }"
   placeholder="Enter your mobile number"
   v-validate="'required'"
   :maxlength="maxmobile"                   
   />
```

Of course, you should declare this variable (in the `data` or the `setup` if you're using composition API).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the disabled attribute and bind it to a variable.
The value should be a boolean, therefore true or false.

```
<input type="text" :disabled = "yourVariable" />
```

Because you call the function verifyOtp on button click, you can change the value of your attribute in the function :)